# How to have the same visual effect of a figure in a non-floating environment

Tags: subfloats, minipage, subcaption

I have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[\footnotesize my_sub_caption1]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{images/my_image1}}
\quad
\subfloat[\footnotesize my_sub_caption2]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{images/my_image2}}
\quad
\subfloat[\footnotesize my_sub_caption3]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{images/my_image3}}
\caption{My caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

which creates a figure with 3 subfigures exactly how I desire.
Now I don't want this image to float: a first solution (the one I used at the moment) is to put a \pagebreak before and after the figure, forcing image position with \begin{figure}[h].
This solution is ok for me because my image has to take a whole page, but I'd love a more systematic approach.
Since I don't want the image to float I tried to use a minipage, with the following code:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/my_image1}
            \captionof{subfigure}{my_sub_caption1}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
    \quad
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/my_image2}
            \captionof{subfigure}{my_sub_caption2}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/my_image3}
        \captionof{subfigure}{my_sub_caption3}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\captionof{figure}{My caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{minipage}
```

This solution actually worked, but my subcaptions haven't got the brackets as in the rest of my work.
Any solutions?

Comment: But what about using `\begin{figure}[p]`?

Comment: It works for my case, as well as using the pagebreak (actually I need it only after, to avoid next section to come before the image). What I am looking for is a systematic way to put some images in a minipage, having the right subcaption

Comment: By the way, thank you for your answer, I didn't know the option [p] for figures :D

Comment: Another option is `\begin{figure}[!h]` (although probably will mess  up with other placements...)

Comment: @SanMosy: Then you might just as well add the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) to your preamble, and use `\begin{figure}[H]`, which technically is the same as using a `minipage`. For more on figure placement, see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD).